# Unable to download complete csv file using axios

Tags: csv, download, axios

I am using [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) to download a csv file from a web service which the user needs to authenticate before downloading the file. Credentials are provided using axio's `auth` option in the request configuration:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const fs = require('fs')

const url = 'someUrlWithEndpoint.php'

axios.get(url, {
    responseType: 'stream',
    auth: {
        username: 'user',
        password: 'pwd'
    },
})
.catch(error => {console.error('ERROR:', error)})
.then(res => {
  console.log(res.data)
  res.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('data.csv'))
})
```

Authentication seems to work, since I receive `200` as `statusCode` and some data is written to the desired file `data.csv`. However, the downloaded data contains the csv header row, only. Other data is missing.

Downloading the data by hand (through the user interface of the web service) gives a correct data file as expected.

To narrow down possible errors in using axios I tried to download another csv (with semicolon as delimiter) file as follows:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const fs = require('fs')

const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Aratramba/ps-barbershop/master/examples/sample-semicolon.csv'

axios.get(url, {
    responseType: 'stream'
})
.catch(error => {console.error('ERROR:', error)})
.then(res => {
  res.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('download.csv'))
})
```

or a even longer sample file (with comma as delimiter):

```
const axios = require('axios')
const fs = require('fs')

const url = 'http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv'

axios.get(url, {
    responseType: 'stream'
})
.catch(error => {console.error('ERROR:', error)})
.then(res => {
  // console.log(res.data)
  res.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('foo.csv'))
})
```

Both examples downloading the csv files work like a charm. However, downloading the desired csv file from my web service in contrast, as written above, gives a file containing the first header row, only. Do you have any suggestions about where to start to debug this issue?